# Find a linear transformation defined by $T(0,1,2) = (3,1,2)$ and $T(1,1,1) = (2,2,2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The transformation here (as per my calculations) will be $T\colon U \rightarrow V$ such that $T(x,y,z) = (y+z, 3y-z, 2y)$ where $z=-x+2y$.

Now what should $U$ be  $\Bbb R^3$ or a subset of $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: There will be many linear maps that do this, since you have only specified where a 2 dimensional subspace goes

Comment: @qbert I could only find a single transformation. Can you hint how to find others?

Comment: To find others just extend $\{(0,1,2),(1,1,1)\}$ to a basis for $\mathbb R^3$.  For instance,  you could use $(1,0,0)$.  Then just map it to different vectors to get other examples.

Comment: If this is exactly the problem as it was presented to you (where did it come from, by the way?), then it’s common to assume that $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ was intended. If this is from some textbook, compare this exercise to other examples and exercises in the book to be sure.

Comment: @amd The question is to just find the transformation. I asked this just as a clarification.

Comment: There’s no way for anyone else to know for sure unless you provide a source or some other context for comparison. At any rate, the right person to ask is whomever is going to be grading your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a linear transformation $T$ such that $T(u_1)=v_1$ and $T(u_2)=v_2$ where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are linearly independent, then we want $T(\alpha u_1+\beta u_2)=\alpha T(u_1)+\beta T(u_2)$ for scalars $\alpha,\beta$, and then $T$ is defined on the subspace $\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2)$. Also, the range will be $\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking the same, but needed some corroboration. Thanks.